# Flutter animation lose control

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

When I use AnimatiedContainer, it is valid if I directly control the animation change of the value of this Container, for example the margin change. But when I add a child inside e.g. Tansform.translate and I try to change the value of offset and add animation (controlled by the same change value as margin above), I lose the animation effect, why is that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.